# Create a route for AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, 8

How should I implement a callback to a single Drupal class (in my case it's Transliteration). I don't need a full Drupal load/bootstrap, but one independent class.

The purpose of the AJAX code would be the following:

- User inputs 'áéíóű'
- The input is sent via AJAX
- The `Transliteration` class changes the input to 'aeiou'
- The result is returned to the client

I've found [this related issue](http://drupal.org/node/1801356), but it would be nice to have a simple example (and documentation) for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How should I implement a callback to a single Drupal class (in my case it's Transliteration). I don't need a full Drupal load/bootstrap just one independent class.

Taken literally, within the confines of Drupal, I don't believe you can. We rely on PSR-0 for class loading, so at the very least you *must* bootstrap Drupal to get the class loader running. (Though not necessarily a *full* bootstrap).

To truly *just* load a single class, you'd need a to call a different file than index.php where you'd hard code the class loading.

I haven't looked at how Ajax requests specifically have changed from D7 => D8, but thanks to D8's [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), only classes that are used in a single request will be instantiated, so the need to try to speed optimize things out, as you seem to want to do, should be lessened.

Comment: Nice, this really works. A simple AJAX request has a 25-35msec response time, instead of the front page response time of 80-100msec on my server. It's enough.

Answer (score 1):

As far as for avoiding to fully bootstrap Drupal to use a callback implemented in a class, I think the answer is not different from the one you would get for Drupal 7: Boostrap Drupal using a custom PHP file.

The fact Drupal is not using anymore the [cron.php file that is used in Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/cron.php/7) leads me to think that fully bootstrapping Drupal is not a performance issue.
It is true that Drupal 8 still has its [authorize.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!authorize.php/8), but that is necessary for a specific case which is not a case most of the modules would need to handle.

If you really need to do it, consider the differences that there are between the [index.php file used from Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/7), and [the same file used by Drupal 8](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/8).
Keep also in mind that, in Drupal 8, AJAX responses are handled with the [AjaxResponse](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Ajax!AjaxResponse.php/class/AjaxResponse/8) class, and soon [the form system will be converted to use the new AJAX API](http://drupal.org/node/1843220).